# How to Enable Submit Button After API Call and Within if Statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am disabling the submit button #myButton after i execute an api call doAjax();

```
    $("#myButton").click(function (e) {
    doAjax();
    $('input:submit').attr("disabled", true);
});
```

But it wont enable after the callback .. i want to enable it if the call back meets a certain criteria i.e.

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "api5.php",
    data: dataString,
    dataType: "json",

    //if received a response from the server
    success: function (response) {
    var status = response.status;
enter code here
if ((status == 'READY' && response.endpoints[0].statusMessage == 'Ready')) { 
$('input:submit').attr("disabled", false);
```

doesn't seem to work though.. button stays disabled.

Comment: `$('input:submit').prop("disabled", false);` - use prop instead of attr

Comment: Based on the click event you posted what is happening is that when you make ajax call and i am assuming that code inside if statement in ajax success is executed,input element of type submit is enabled but soon after  you disabled the button in click event. that is why i think your button is not enabled

Comment: i tried .prop as well but didn't work .. if i put it outside the if statement then it works.. no idea why but i have other data in the if statement and they all execute and i see the data on the page..

Comment: shrawan_lakhe, i think you might be on to something as noone of the suggested solutions seem to re-enable the button. Any other way i can deal with this? The key thing is I need to enable the submit button within the if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sue the your if block is getting executed ? Try doing console.log or alert inside the if block. Also, try the following :

```
$('input:submit').removeAttr('disabled');
```

or you can also try input[type=submit] as the selector or give a class or id and make it selector.

Comment: if statement is definitely running because the results are displayed on the page, the only thing that's not executed it the enable submit button...

Comment: hmm, just tried again and it seems your first solution work.
$('input:submit').removeAttr('disabled');

Answer (score 0):

the code works for me, only comment this line `enter code here`

```
 $.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: "api5.php",
 data: dataString,
 dataType: "json",

 //if received a response from the server
 success: function (response) {
 var status = response.status;
 //enter code here
      if ((status == 'READY' && response.endpoints[0].statusMessage == 'Ready')) { 
           $('input:submit').attr("disabled", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  : `$(el).prop('disabled', false)`